# NumberField text align since react-admin 2.1.3

Tags: react-admin

The release 2.1.3 of `react-admin` introduced the use of `<Typography />` for the `NumberField` component (and others) in place of `<span />`.

This component has a style to align text on the right.

```
const styles = {
    input: { textAlign: 'right' },
};
```

I don't know why, but with the `span` element the number was aligned left.
Now the number is aligned right, but not aligned with the same margin if there are others number fields.

[Code demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lykrqwj72q) (Comment show screen) / [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI8u2.png)

I tried to define a `className` on my component...

```
<NumberField source="id" className="leftalign" />
```

with

```
.leftalign {
    text-align: left;
}
```

...but the class is overridden by the style-generated class `NumberField-input-234` (except if I set `!important` but I would like to avoid this).

My questions are:

- Is there a way to align them on the left without the uggly `!important` css flag or writing `style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}` each time I use a `<NumberField />`?
- Is there a way to align right with the same margin?

Thanks

Comment: Confirmed it's a bug. We used to be able to pass a `textAlign` prop which is ignored now... Can you open an issue ?

Comment: Thanks @GildasGarcia. Here is the issue : https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2098

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in `react-admin@2.2.0`